# it keeps showing me undefined and idk whats the reason

Tags: javascript, forms

this is my HTML which is basically just a form with two inputs and h2, whatever i write in the input and submit will be shown under the h2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Event Basics</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="tweeting" action="/idk">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" />
        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
        <input style="padding-bottom: 30px" type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Whats happening?" />
        <button>Tweet Out</button>
    </form>

    <h2>TimeLine</h2>
    <ul id="tweets"></ul>
    <script src="app.js "></script>
</body>

</html>
```

this is my javascript which should take the inputs and bold them and append all stuff to a list which is like a temp timeline that will disappear after I refresh but thats not the issue:

```
//selecting the form
const tweeting = document.querySelector('#tweeting');
// selecting the ul which will be as a timeline
const timeLine = document.querySelector('#tweets');

//this function will just capture the inputs from the form after submitting it, we will save to a variable and call the function that will add our tweet to the ul (timeline)

tweeting.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
// saving the username
    const usernameInput = tweeting.elements.username;
//saving the tweet
    const tweetInput = tweeting.elements.comment;
//calling the function
    addTweet(usernameInput.input, tweetInput.input)
    usernameInput.value = '';
    tweetInput.value = '';

})

const addTweet = (username, tweet) => {
// creating a new item that will be added to the timeline at the end
    const newTweet = document.createElement("li");
//we wanted to make the username in bold so the next two lines is to do that
    const bTag = document.createElement('b');
    bTag.append(username);
// appended the username in bold
    newTweet.append(bTag);
// appended the tweet
    newTweet.append(`- ${tweet}`);
// added to the timeline
    timeLine.append(newTweet);
}
```

I dont know why it show me **undefined** -undefined

Answer (score 2):

You need to use usernameInput.value not input in your call to addTweet.

```
//calling the function
addTweet(usernameInput.value, tweetInput.value)
```

Full code shown below.

```js
//selecting the form
const tweeting = document.querySelector('#tweeting');
// selecting the ul which will be as a timeline
const timeLine = document.querySelector('#tweets');


tweeting.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
// saving the username
    const usernameInput = tweeting.elements.username;
//saving the tweet
    const tweetInput = tweeting.elements.comment;
//calling the function
    addTweet(usernameInput.value, tweetInput.value)
    usernameInput.value = '';
    tweetInput.value = '';

})

const addTweet = (username, tweet) => {
// creating a new item that will be added to the timeline at the end
    const newTweet = document.createElement("li");
//we wanted to make the username in bold so the next two lines is to do that
    const bTag = document.createElement('b');
    bTag.append(username);
// appended the username in bold
    newTweet.append(bTag);
// appended the tweet
    newTweet.append(`- ${tweet}`);
// added to the timeline
    timeLine.append(newTweet);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Event Basics</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="tweeting" action="/idk">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" />
        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
        <input style="padding-bottom: 30px" type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Whats happening?" />
        <button>Tweet Out</button>
    </form>

    <h2>TimeLine</h2>
    <ul id="tweets"></ul>
    <script src="app.js "></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have done that and a new weird problem appeared which is when I click submit the form does it action (goes to /idk) which shouldnt bcz I used e.preventDefault() ... any idea why thats happening?

Comment: @AlooyDaBoss You need to remove this line #this function will just capture the inputs from the form after submitting it, we will save to a variable and call the function that will add our tweet to the ul (timeline) from your javascript. This caused it to go to /idk for me too.

Comment: I dont have it in my js file I just wrote it here for the people to understand what the function does and I used # by mistake (I used python)

Comment: I remembered u told me to use e.stopPropagation() .. isnt that for bubbling handling and stuff that are nested? when you mentioned it I went to read about it and didnt worked when I used it, maybe my usage of form isnt correct and shouldve used smth else